# HTML5 doctype causes different rendering of button in webkit

Tags: html, webkit, doctype

I have a form with a button element. In Chrome, it renders as a rounded button when the doctype is html 4 transitional. When switching to HTML5 doctype, the button becomes square. Can someone explain why this happens?

[image: html4]

[image: html5]

Alright, here are links to two examples. First one is html4 and second is html5.

http://mattoettinger.com/test/button.html

http://mattoettinger.com/test/button2.html

Comment: Maybe show us some code and CSS?

Comment: If it's just the doctype you're changing, the browser might switch to a different mode (probably quirks to standard). 

What's the CSS you use to style that button? It might not be entirely valid CSS, and rules might suddenly get dropped in the current browser mode.

Comment: Same exact CSS for these elements. Just changing doctype triggers the change.

Comment: Can you give us the css?  maybe do a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: Your links only have the HTML on the pages, not CSS. The answer most likely lies within the CSS.

Comment: @fivedigit - that is my point. no css is needed to replicate the issue. just the changing of the doctype. Why does everyone keep asking for css? the only difference between the two links is the doctype.

Comment: The doctype is indeed the only difference, since both of the above linked pages look the same in Chrome for me.

Comment: I've checked on 3 separate Macs using the latest prod Chrome and these two pages are different on each one. First one is a rounded button. Second is a square button. Are you on Chrome on a Mac?

Comment: I'm guessing you are on Windows. I just checked in that and they appear the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely is because of quirksmode, buttons are rendered differently. You should only use HTML5 doctype. [Mozilla has a list of properties that are different in quirksmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior). FWIW, it is not that different in quirksmode in Opera, seems to be the case only in Webkit-rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some googling, I've read that html5 form buttons have some new responsibilities and features, which means the button element was definitely touched, however I can't explain the difference. ([html specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/))

**HOWEVER**, I do vaguely remember html5 also making some changes in terms of the way inline elements & block elements are defined. You may want to try giving them displey: block or display: inline and seeing if it affects its rendering / ability to take a height and width / shape

Comment: If I change the img inside the button to be display:block, that does make the button appear rounded. But that breaks the layout of the form and besides that, my main question is why the doctype changes the rendering of the button if the css is the exact same.

Comment: the truth is, you may be missing the fact that your css is incomplete because each different doctype has implications about block level vs inline level rendering of elements, which means css will behave differently. So, please give us your css also.